# T-SQL Fastforward Cursor vs. foreach

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql

i want to caluclate the distance between gps-point to get the complete distance between the first an last point.

My question is: What is faster?

- To load all rows into a DataTable and
  calculate it in c#.net via foreach
  or
- Caluclate it on Sql-Server using a
  StoredProcedure with a FastForward
  Cursor.

I talk of a amout of about 400,000 rows.

Comment: The fastest would be to calculate it **on the server**, but **without a cursor**.....

Comment: @marc_s: Is there a way to add a distance for each row without a cursor?

Comment: See my response - you're not giving us lots of details, so I can only provide a very generalized idea....

Comment: Are you needing to calculate a running total or just one aggregate figure? If it is a running total then using the CLR can give you a kind of super fast cursor that out performs set based methods given the current limited implementation of the `OVER` clause in SQL Server http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2006/07/12/running-sums-yet-again-sqlclr-saves-the-day.aspx

Comment: In some situations, the best way to do it might be to load all the rows onto the local machine and keep a cached copy of it, only occasionally contacting the server for updated copies of its data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would definitely try to do this on the server - try to avoid dragging down 400'000 rows just to calculate a single number (in the end).

Also: I would try to do it **without a cursor** , if ever possible. Cursors are a nightmare on SQL Server - they should be avoided at all costs.

In your case - not knowing your detailed table structure - you could definitely do e.g. a recursive CTE (Common Table Expression) that starts with the first element and a total distance of 0.0, and then recursively sums up all other way points, calculating the distance between point (x+1) and point x, and summing up to the previous total.

At the end, you should have a CTE that shows all way points, all distances between any two waypoints, and the total distance of the entire journey.

That CTE would be something like:

```
;WITH Waypoints AS
(
    -- anchor your query
    SELECT
       WaypointID, PrevWaypointID, Long, Lat, 0.0 as Distance, 0.0 as SumOfDistance
    FROM
       dbo.Waypoint
    WHERE
       PrevWaypointID IS NULL  --  or some other condition

    UNION  -- recurse

    SELECT
       WaypointID, Long, Lat, 
       dbo.GetDistanceBetween(wp.WaypointID, pts.WaypointID),   -- distance
       pts.SumOfDistance + dbo.GetDistanceBetween(wp.WaypointID, pts.WaypointID)  -- sum
    FROM
       dbo.Waypoint wp
    INNER JOIN
       Waypoints pts ON wp.PrevWaypointID = pts.WaypointID          
    WHERE
       (some condition; ID = 1 or PreviousWaypointID IS NULL or something)
)
SELECT * FROM Waypoints
```

Comment: Where's the ORDER BY or do I miss something?

Comment: @Jonas Elfström: no ORDER BY needed - there's *one* row that's the anchor, and then from then on, it's always a `SomeRow.PrevWaypointID = previousRow.WaypointID` connection - the order is defined by the relation between one waypoint and it's previous one.

Comment: Ah, missed the linked list construction.

Comment: Is it right, that this is only applicapable if you have a maximum of 100 points? I get an exception if I try this with more than 100 points: "The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion."

Comment: @sprinter252: the 100 is the **default** for the maximum recursion level of a CTE - yes. However, you *can* increase that - if you want - by specifying `SELECT * FROM Waypoints OPTION (MAXRECURSION 2500)` - or whatever you like (up to a max value of 32767, I believe). More recursion level use more memory, though....

Answer (score 3):

If you are using SQL Server 2008 I would recommend trying to store them as the `geography` type and then

```
declare @point1 geography = 'POINT (-42 84)';
declare @point2 geography = 'POINT (-3 10)';
select @point1.STDistance (@point2)
```

but to really know what is fastest you have to try both.

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that even using a Cursor in SQL, it is still orders of magnitude faster than iterating in front-side code. At the time, ADO and DAO were the technologies in question, so things may have changed a little with the advent of ADO.NET and DataSets.

However, I am betting that T-SQL, being designed specifically for this type of thing, is still more efficient.

The exception would might be if you need to apply special logic during your iteration, but I ssupect that a properly set up SQL Cursor, performing your calculation on the back side, will outperform the Dataset.

Best of all would be to do it without the cursor in SQL, if you are able . . .

Comment: I was posting while others were giving better answers . . .

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Sql Server 2008 (or newer), then you can do everything on the server using the geography type.  Here's a sample for calculating the distance between two points:

```
SELECT geography::Point(lat1, lon1, 4326).STDistance(geography::Point(lat2, lon2, 4326))
```

I'm not sure if this can be used without a cursor, but maybe.

If you're using an older version of SQL Server, then you could still write the distance formula yourself as a stored proc, and do everything server-side as well.

Downloading the entire set to a client and doing all the calculations client-side will almost certainly take much longer, since the download time will be much larger than the calculation time.